# Is there a text-based OSK for Ubuntu linux or nodejs?

Tags: command-line, tablet, ncurses

I'm looking for a soft keyboard that runs *inside* a terminal session on the server-- i.e. TUI not GUI, for use with a touch-screen like phone or tab, using something like ncurses or blessed (node.js would be preferable).  I'm thinking it would be handy for use connecting from mobile terminal emulators without the need for a specific IME or terminal app installed.

Anyone ever hear of such a thing?  This seems like something that would already exist for Ubuntu and other deb-based headless servers.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. I haven't seen any of the popular SSH clients sending on touch input signals to the server (or mouse clicks, for that matter).

Comment: Xterm, rxvt, urxvt, gnome terminal, xfce terminal can send mouse events via ansi-like escape sequences-- basically an xterm-based sub-protocol.  If your TERM type is 'xterm', 'xterm-color', etc. and you fire-up Midnight Commander, for instance, you can use your mouse-- even over ssh.   Termux on Android lets you use touchscreen and mouse if your device supports it.  Xterm.js for the web sends mouse as well.  Apps  can pick up these codes using ncurses or manually.   If your TERM is VT100 etc. won't work though.   You're TERM has to tell it it's xterm-based.

Comment: exactly - all those send ANSI escape codes, which some programs interpret as mouse clicks or scrolling or whatever. So unless somebody standardised things like long touch or 3d pressing, etc., that's not in the same league as simple mouse clicks.

Comment: Also, any such OSK would have to wrap the program somehow to capture the ANSI sequences so received and interpret it for the app as a keypress.

Comment: Generally I've noticed a pattern between mouse, touchpad, and touchscreen-- also some gui remote utilities.  A touch is a left click.  Long press, or two-finger touch is a right click.  Three-finger touch is a middle click.  Edge-swipe or two-finger swipe is scroll, so it's mouse-wheel.  Ardp/Bvnc use two-finger taps for right-click.  Xterm can send up and/or down for left, right,  and middle buttons, wheel up, wheel down, and XY coordinates, even live.  Termux, for instance, sends mouse codes in response to touch events, including wheel from swipe.  The others too, I think, on touchscreen.

Comment: Yes.  Probably.  I'm thinking like 'screen' or 'tmux'.  It would have to divide the window and display two screens, one for the keyboard, another for the cli.  Actually, I think 'screen' could be used for that part, but it'd be better not being dependent.

Comment: Hmm.  You just sparked an idea.  I considered writing one before, but thought it would be more involved than I have time for.  May be simpler than I first thought.  As to standardization, I think xterm-color is pretty much the norm linux terminals identify themselves as.  VT100 is more common on pre-Windows 10 I believe, but 10 has a native linux built-in, so there's that.  Anyway,  the codes don't need to be directly interpreted (although they can be).  That's what terminfo is for, and ncurses.  So your program can get the sequences assigned to your TERM.